# How to automatically increment a custom primary key when a new row is inserted

Tags: sqlite

I want each table in the database to have a prefix in its primary key. For example, the first row in the table `EMPLOYERS` should have an id of `EMP_00000001` and so on. How can i make it so that each new row inserted has an id of `EMP_00000002, ...03, ...`, preferably with a trigger?

Comment: Why not simply use a rowid or an autoincremented column? I cannot really see the advantage of prefixing the primary key with a string.

Comment: @GMB You're probably right, but I'm attempting a hybrid SQL & mongo database so  I will be using those ID's to match data between the 2. The prefix is just there to accommodate possible future needs (which I honestly haven't thought of yet). Is the whole incrementing thing impossible? Because I will drop it if it is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of fighting against how Sqlite works, just add the prefix to a normal rowid when it's needed (Maybe wrap it in a view if you'll use the long version in a lot of different queries to avoid unnecessary duplication), and stick to the plain number internally in joins, foreign keys, etc. for efficiency:

```
CREATE TABLE employee_data(id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, name);
CREATE VIEW employees(id, name) AS SELECT printf('EMP_%08d', id), name FROM employee_data;
INSERT INTO employee_data(name) VALUES ('Bill'), ('Paul');
SELECT * FROM employees;
```

```
id            name
------------  ----------
EMP_00000001  Bill
EMP_00000002  Paul
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Update Emp set EMPLOYERS = EMPLOYERS + 1 where rowid=1
```

Comment: `EMPLOYERS` is the name of the table. The primary key of the table has the form `EMP_XXXXXX` where `XXXXXX` is the row number. So let's say i have  50 entries, when i insert the 51th, i would like it to have a primary key of `EMP_000051`.

Comment: Set the column as autoincrement and when you do an insert leave it empty and it will auto increment to EMP_...51

Comment: Auto increment works only on integer values, whereas the key is a string. It won't work

Comment: You can do a count on the table and then insert a new row by adding 1 to it

Comment: SELECT COUNT(*) FROM EMP;
then store the value of count in a variable and then do an insert by adding 1 to it.